# Append currently logged in user to JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, fs

I am trying to find a way to get the currently logged in user and than append them to a JSON file. Below is my code to first read the dir, then get the most recent file, return it and then append the current user that is logged in.

I can append a string to the file but when trying to perform `req.user` it states

> Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

What would I need to include in this file so that it knows what `user` is?

```
let fs                    = require("fs"),
        express               = require("express"),
        _                     = require("underscore"),
        User                  = require("./models/user"),
        path                  = require("path");
    
    let getFileAddUser = () => { 
        let filePath = '../automation_projects/wss-automation-u/results/temp/';
        fs.readdir(filePath, (err, files) => {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            let file = getMostRecentFile(files, filePath);
            console.log(file);
            fs.readFile(filePath + file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
                let json = JSON.parse(data);
                if(err){
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                } else {
                    //Un-comment to write to most recent file.
                    //==================================================
                    //This should find the currently logged in user and append them to the most recent file found.
                    json.currentuser = req.user;
                    fs.writeFile(filePath + file, JSON.stringify(json), (error) => {
                        if(error){
                            console.error(error);
                            return;
                        } else {
                            console.log(json);
                        }
                    });
                    //==================================================
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    };
    
    //Get the most recent file from the results folder.
    function getMostRecentFile(files, path) {
        let out = [];
        files.forEach(function(file) {
            let stats = fs.statSync(path + "/" +file);
            if(stats.isFile()) {
                out.push({"file":file, "mtime": stats.mtime.getTime()});
            }
        });
        out.sort(function(a,b) {
            return b.mtime - a.mtime;
        })
        return (out.length>0) ? out[0].file : "";
    }
    
    module.exports = getFileAddUser;
```

Comment: `fs.readFile(filePath + file, 'utf8', (err, data, req)` what is `req`  doing there ?

Comment: callback function has only two parameters `error , data`

Comment: Okay, so how can I capture the currently logged in user from a module?

Comment: create a route. Hit this route from frontend and send some information to this route. And then do whatever you want it to do

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a knowledgeable co-worker and some further research we were able to get this working. I'd like to share the code we came up with to append the currently logged in user to our results file. You will also notice we got some help using the Ramada.js library.

```
let fs                    = require("fs"),
    express               = require("express"),
    _                     = require("underscore"),
    User                  = require("./models/user"),
    r                     = require("ramda"),
    path                  = require("path");



 //This will be our function to get the most recent file from our dir and 
      //return it to us. We than user this function below.
function getMostRecentFile(files, path) {
    let out = [];
    let f = r.tail(files);
    console.log(files);
    f.forEach(function(file) {
        let stats = fs.statSync(path + "/" +file);
        if(stats.isFile()) {
            out.push({"file":file, "mtime": stats.mtime.getTime()});
        }
    });
    out.sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.mtime - a.mtime;
    })
    return (out.length>0) ? out[0].file : "";
}

//Passing in 'u' as a argument which can than be used in a route and pass in 
//anything that we want it to be. In our case it was the currently logged 
//in user.
let getUser = (u) => {
    let user = u;
    let filePath = '../automation_projects/wss-automation-u/results/temp/';
    //Comment above and uncomment below for testing locally.
    // let filePath = "./temp/";
    let file = "";
     //Below we read our dir then get the most recent file using the 
    //getMostRecentfile function above.
    read_directory(filePath).then( files => {
        file = getMostRecentFile(files, filePath)
        console.log(file);
        return(read_file(filePath + file))
    }).then( x => {
    // Here we parse through our data with x representing the data that we 
    //returned above.
            let json = JSON.parse(x);
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            json.currentuser = u;
            //And finally we write to the end of the latest file.
            fs.writeFile(filePath + file, JSON.stringify(json), (error) => {
                if(error) reject(error);
                else resolve(json);
                // console.log(json);
            });
        });
    });
}

let read_directory = (path) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readdir(path, (err, items) => {
        if (err){
          return reject(err)
        }
        return resolve([path, ...items])
      })
    })
   }

   let read_file = (path) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile(path, "utf8", (err, items) => {
        if (err){
          return reject(err)
        }
        return resolve(items)
      })
    })
   }

   module.exports = getUser;
```

Than below is an example route with how to use the getUser module. You will want to require it like you do everything else with node.js and dependencies. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
let getUser = require("getuser");


//Make a route to use the getUser module and pass in our argument value.
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
//With in the get user function pass in whatever you want to equal 'u' from the getuser module.
   getUser(req.user.username);
   res.render("index", { username: req.user });
});
```